# Scatterplot not accessing y value data (Python)

Tags: python, list, dictionary, scatter-plot

I’m in need of some fresh eyes. I’m attempting to plot a scatter plot using the values from list x and y.

Even though I have a list of x and y values for df.plot.scatter("x", "y"), when running the code an error appears stating that

`TypeError: scatter() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'`

I don’t know what I’m missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

  #sample lists
hole_ID = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
x = [1, 2, 4, 6, 4, 6]
y = [1, 5, 3, 3, 9, 6]


  # Assign Drill_hole ID as Key, all other lists as values

dict_database = dict(zip(hole_ID, zip(x, y)))

  # Create Dataframe and assign dict_database to it

df = DataFrame
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_database, orient='index', columns=["x", "y"])

  # Create and display Scatterplot

scatter1 = df.plot.scatter("x", "y")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you did a mistake by forgetting to define df:

> df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_database, orient='index', columns=["x",
> "y"])

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

  #sample lists
hole_ID = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
x = [1, 2, 4, 6, 4, 6]
y = [1, 5, 3, 3, 9, 6]


  # Assign Drill_hole ID as Key, all other lists as values

dict_database = dict(zip(hole_ID, zip(x, y)))

  # Create Dataframe and assign dict_database to it

df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_database, orient='index', columns=["x", "y"])

  # Create and display Scatterplot

scatter1 = df.plot.scatter("x", "y")
plt.show()
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks Renaud!

I think that I need to step away from the keyboard for a bit.